# Реализация инерции и модель сопротивления шара

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Условие задачи:**

Реализуйте систему разноразмерных частиц, имеющих одинаковую вертикальную скорость. При прохождении границы сред частицами должны испытывать сопротивление.
Реализуйте более физически достоверную модель сопротивления, зависящего от размера частицы.
Добавьте учёт инерции частиц в зависимости от их массы.

**Вопрос:**

Как можно реализовать правильно модель сопротивления (у меня реализовано это умножением радиуса частицы на коэффициент 0.2 и по сути взято из головы), такая же проблема и с инерцией частиц. Движение частицы задано в функциях move_ball, iter_1, iter_2, iter_3, iter_stop.

**Код:**

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Силы Сопротивления")
width = 600
height = 600
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg="black")
c.pack()
c.create_rectangle(0, height//2, width+2, height+2, fill='grey')

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, c, x1, y1, x2, y2, radius, color="white"):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.radius = radius
        self.c = c
        # resistance можно придумать что-нибудь интереснее
        self.resistance = radius*0.2
        self.ball = c.create_oval(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill=color, outline='white', width=2)

    def move_ball(self):
        
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] < 300:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, 9)
            c.after(1000//60, self.move_ball)
        elif 300 <= c.coords(self.ball)[3] < 600:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, self.resistance)
            c.after(1000//60, self.move_ball)
        elif c.coords(self.ball)[3] >= 600:
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_1)

    def iter_1(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] >= 585:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, -self.resistance)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_1)
        elif c.coords(self.ball)[3] <= 600:
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_2)
            
    def iter_2(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] < 600:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, 0.4*self.resistance)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_2)
        else:
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_3)

    def iter_3(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] >= 595:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, 0.2*-self.resistance)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_3)
        elif c.coords(self.ball)[3] <= 600:
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_stop)

    def iter_stop(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] <= 600:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, 0.5)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_stop)
        



# Создание частиц 
# <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
r1 = 20
ball1 = Ball(c, 100 - r1, 120 - r1, 100 + r1, 120 + r1, r1, color="#a0a0a0")
ball1.move_ball()

r2 = 30
ball2 = Ball(c, 200 - r2, 120 - r2, 200 + r2, 120 + r2, r2, color="#a0a0a0")
ball2.move_ball()

r3 = 10
ball2 = Ball(c, 300 - r3, 120 - r3, 300 + r3, 120 + r3, r3, color="#a0a0a0")
ball2.move_ball()

r4 = 35
ball2 = Ball(c, 400 - r4, 120 - r4, 400 + r4, 120 + r4, r4, color="#a0a0a0")
ball2.move_ball()

r4 = 15
ball2 = Ball(c, 530 - r4, 120 - r4, 530 + r4, 120 + r4, r4, color="#a0a0a0")
ball2.move_ball()
# <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Возьмите формулу [лобового сопротивления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) за основу. Можно упростить формулу до `F = C * v**2 * S`, где v - скорость, S - площадь (для простоты можно просто подставлять размер), C - коэффициент, просто подбираете опытным путем. Так получаете силу сопротивления, дальше расчитываете ускорение как `a = F / m`, так получите зависимость от массы.

Comment: Можно попробовать, я уже читал про лобовое сопротивление. Однако мне оно показалось сложным из-за аэродинамического коэффициента сопротивления в формуле. Упрощенный вариант подойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Получившийся код:**

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Силы Сопротивления")
width = 600
height = 600
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg="black")
c.pack()
c.create_rectangle(0, height//2, width+2, height+2, fill='grey')


class Ball:

    def __init__(self, c, x1, y1, x2, y2, radius, mass, color="white"):

        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.radius = radius
        self.c = c

        self.v = 4
        self.F_str = 0.015 * self.v * radius
        self.mass = mass
        self.Acceleration = (self.F_str / mass) * 50
        self.ball = c.create_oval(self.x1 - self.radius, self.y1 - self.radius, self.x2 +
                                  self.radius, self.y2 + self.radius, fill=color, outline='white', width=2)

    def move_ball(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] < height//2:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, self.v)
            c.after(1000//60, self.move_ball)
        elif height//2 <= c.coords(self.ball)[3] + self.F_str < height:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, self.F_str)
            c.after(1000//60, self.move_ball)
        else:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, height + 1 - c.coords(self.ball)[3])
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_1)

    def iter_1(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] - self.Acceleration >= height - self.mass*0.2:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, -self.Acceleration)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_1)
        elif c.coords(self.ball)[3] <= height:
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_2)

    def iter_2(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] + self.Acceleration < height:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, self.Acceleration)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_2)
        else:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, height + 1 - c.coords(self.ball)[3])
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_3)

    def iter_3(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] - self.Acceleration >= height - self.mass*0.1:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, -self.Acceleration)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_3)
        else:
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_stop)

    def iter_stop(self):
        if c.coords(self.ball)[3] + self.Acceleration < height:
            c.move(self.ball, 0, self.Acceleration)
            c.after(1000//60, self.iter_stop)

        else:
            # Конечная координата частицы равна height + 1
            c.move(self.ball, 0, height + 1 - c.coords(self.ball)[3])


def esc(event):
    root.destroy()


root.bind('<Escape>', esc)


# Создание частиц
# <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
r1 = 40
mass1 = 60
ball1 = Ball(c, 100, 20, 100,
             20, r1, mass1, color="#a0a0a0")
ball1.move_ball()

r2 = 25
mass2 = 50
ball2 = Ball(c, 200, 20, 200,
             20, r2, mass2, color="#a0a0a0")
ball2.move_ball()

r3 = 20
mass3 = 40
ball3 = Ball(c, 300, 20, 300,
             20, r3, mass3, color="#a0a0a0")
ball3.move_ball()

r4 = 36
mass4 = 75
ball4 = Ball(c, 400, 20, 400,
             20, r4, mass4, color="#a0a0a0")
ball4.move_ball()

r5 = 15
mass5 = 10
ball5 = Ball(c, 510, 20, 510,
             20, r5, mass5, color="#a0a0a0")
ball5.move_ball()


r6 = 25
mass6 = 30
ball6 = Ball(c, 570, 20, 570,
             20, r6, mass6, color="#a0a0a0")
ball6.move_ball()
# <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


root.mainloop()
```